# Integrate report from Reporting server 2016 via iframe in SharePoint 2013

Tags: iframe, sharepoint, reporting-services, report, embed

I'm trying to integrate a Report from Reporting Server2016 into our SharePoint2013.
It worked fine with Reporting Server 2012 but not anymore with the new enviroment.

I've alread read a bit around and found out that the Reporting Server is sending the Report with X-Frame-Options = SAMEORIGIN in the answer header.

Is there the possibility to turn that off in the Reporting server?

Installing a Browser Plugin that ignores the header is not an option.

Comment: If you load the iFrame link in a separate window what do you get?

Answer (score 16):

Starting from RS 2016 you can append rs:Embed=true to report URL, it will remove X-Frame-Options from response. Your report URL then will look this:

```
http://your-server-name/reports/path/and/reportname?rs:Embed=true
```

Prooflink: [SSRS team blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2016/09/23/embed-paginated-reports-into-asp-net-web-apps-using-the-report-viewer-2016-control/)